# How can I save query data from another mongoDB to the collection of DB I am currently connected to?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multiple-databases

I've got two databases and I want to write data from another DB in the collection.

I am connected to a mongoDB with
`mongoose.connect("mongodb://XXX:YYY@localhost:27017/realtime?authSource=admin"`

and writing into a collection based on the Model I currently use.

There is one key-value-pair (it's a timestamp) I need from a different DB which runs on the same port `mongodb://XXX:YYY@localhost:27017/timetable?authSource=admin`.

Here is a snippet, hope that'll help.

```
    EntityModel
    .find({})
    .limit(10)
    .then((entities) => {
      entities.forEach((entity) => {

        // this is where I need to access the other DB
        // to get arrivalTimetable from the timetable database for Each entity

            tripData.stops.push({
              stop_id: stu.stopId,
              arrivalTimetable: arrivalTimetable,
              arrivalRealtime: arrivalRT
            });
        const tripDelay = new TripDelay(tripData);
        trip.save();
}
```

What is a good way, to get the data needed and save it to the current collection?

Answer (score 0):

[$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) allows output to a different database.